# "OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'" for an Amazon ElastiCache Redis

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm getting `"OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'"` error **from time to time** when trying to insert into an Elasticache redis node.

I went from a self-managed redis instance (maxmemory = 12Go, maxmemory-policy = allkeys-lru) to an Elasticache redis one (r5.large, i.e. maxmemory = 14 Go, maxmemory-policy = allkeys-lru).

However, after the migration of keys I'm getting `"OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'"` error from time to time that I don't manage to understand.

I've checked what they recommend here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/oom-command-not-allowed-redis/ to solve the problem but so far:

1. I have a TTL on all keys
2. I'm already in allkeys-lru
3. When I look at the node freeable memory I have about 7Go available

Here is the output when `INFO memory`

```
# Memory
used_memory:10526693040
used_memory_human:9.80G
used_memory_rss:11520012288
used_memory_rss_human:10.73G
used_memory_peak:10560011952
used_memory_peak_human:9.83G
used_memory_peak_perc:99.68%
used_memory_overhead:201133315
used_memory_startup:4203584
used_memory_dataset:10325559725
used_memory_dataset_perc:98.13%
allocator_allocated:10527575720
allocator_active:11510194176
allocator_resident:11667750912
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:10527885773
maxmemory_human:9.80G
maxmemory_policy:allkeys-lru
allocator_frag_ratio:1.09
allocator_frag_bytes:982618456
allocator_rss_ratio:1.01
allocator_rss_bytes:157556736
rss_overhead_ratio:0.99
rss_overhead_bytes:-147738624
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.09
mem_fragmentation_bytes:993361528
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:1048576
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:153411
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

If you have any clue for how to solve this. 
Thanks!

Comment: Consider posting relevant lines from `INFO memory` command, to see peak and rss

Comment: @LeoMurillo I just updated the description. From what I see I have a `used_memory_dataset_perc ` really high. But isn't eviction used to prevent insertion from failing?

Answer (score 0):

ElastiCache makes use of EC2 instances, like the r5.large with 16Gib memory in your example. But, you'll note that the instance types for ElastiCache are always prefixed with `cache.` and they are slightly different. If you look up these instances in [ElastiCache pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/), you'll see they have a different value for memory. For cache.r5.large, the amount of memory available for storing data in-memory is 13.07GiB.

That's the reason you see 7GiB of free memory, it's the overall free memory of the instance, in that case 16GiB - but you can't make use of all of that memory. Only of 13.07GiB out of it.

On top of that, ElastiCache also manages [reserved memory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/redis-memory-management.html). Reserved memory is memory set aside for nondata use (Like backups, failovers, etc.). The default is 25% (For all clusters created after after March 16, 2017)  - that's why your maxmemory is set to 9.8GiB.

Given you followed the recommendations you mentioned, for when the used memory is higher than maxmemory, there are two options as I see it:

1. Decrease the reserved memory. However, this might pose a risk for nondata operations as mentioned above.
2. Scale up/out so you'll less memory on each node.